# Reading nodes with&without namespace tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml, namespaces

I need to read xml documents like this :

```
<wcs:CoverageOffering>
<wcs:description>Generated from GeoTIFF</wcs:description>
<wcs:name>ndh:ndh-cyclone-mortality-risks-distribution</wcs:name>
                            ....
```

But in some servers the xml document is implemented without namespace tag :

```
<CoverageOffering>
<description>Generated from GeoTIFF</description>
<name>ndh:ndh-cyclone-mortality-risks-distribution</name>
                         ....
```

How can I read both in an efficient way? (I wrote if else statements for each node to control this condition but it seems not a good way to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XmlDocument` and add `wcs` namespace to `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(...);
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("wcs", "http://...your ns");

var nl = document.SelectNodes("your xpath", nsmgr);
```

Comment: using xmlnamespacemanager class make the code better thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this XML Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/).  It will use a namespace if needed.

You can use it like:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
string description = root.Get("path/to/description", default(string));
```

or

```
string description = root.XGetElement("//description", default(string));
```

The `default(string)` is for type conversion for either Get.  You can pass any default you desire.