# How to Read XML element with namespace value

Tags: c#, xml

I am facing problem in fetching xml element value if it is having name space. please help me what is the problem here. My xml string is below

```
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:aw="http://www.adventure-works.com"> <aw:ShippingAddress> <aw:Name>John</aw:Name> <aw:Street>123 Main St.</aw:Street> <aw:City>Seattle</aw:City> <aw:State>WA</aw:State> <aw:Zip>98113</aw:Zip> <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country> </aw:ShippingAddress> <aw:ShippingAddress> <aw:Name>Chris Preston</aw:Name> <aw:Street>123 Robin St.</aw:Street> <aw:City>Newyork</aw:City> <aw:State>TU</aw:State> <aw:Zip>98113</aw:Zip> <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country> </aw:ShippingAddress> <aw:ShippingAddress> <aw:Name>Charlis</aw:Name> <aw:Street>53 Jacob St.</aw:Street> <aw:City>California</aw:City> <aw:State>DOWNTOWN</aw:State> <aw:Zip>98111</aw:Zip> <aw:Country>USA</aw:Country> </aw:ShippingAddress> </aw:PurchaseOrder>
```

my code is below

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
List<PurchaseOrder> listWO = new List<PurchaseOrder>();

 foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    if ( el.Elements().Count() > 0)
        {
        PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder
        {
            Name = el.Elements("aw:Name").First().Value,
            City = el.Elements("aw:City").First().Value,
            Country = el.Elements("aw:Country").First().Value
        };
        listPO.Add(po):
    }
 }
```

Here i am not getting the value of each "ShippingAddress" wise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading nodes with&without namespace tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768228/reading-nodes-withwithout-namespace-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See changes below :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
            XNamespace awNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("aw");
            List<PurchaseOrder> listWO = new List<PurchaseOrder>();

             foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                if ( el.Elements().Count() > 0)
                    {
                    PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder
                    {
                        Name = el.Elements(awNs + "Name").First().Value,
                        City = el.Elements(awNs + "City").First().Value,
                        Country = el.Elements(awNs + "Country").First().Value
                    };
                    listPO.Add(po):
                }
             }
```